# Jsoup parsing single URL and multiple bodies (maybe fragmented)

Tags: java, html, android-studio, dom, jsoup

I am trying to get a HTML page using `jsoup`, but I am only getting the first page. Please note that the website will only *sometimes* have multiple pages.

Background:
The link is for my transportation from work. Since my station is changing daily, I wanted to make an app that will let me know where my station will be today instead of browsing the list myself every day.

So the code takes the list `URL` and parses it with `jsoup`. It uses `Pattern.compile` to extract the date from the body element, but I have only figured out how to get the first page/first body. How can I get all of the pages/bodies?

```
package androidcodesnippets.me.cfsuman.com.mystation;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String USGS =
        "http://yit.maya-tour.co.il/yit-pass/Drop_Report.aspx? 
client_code=2660&coordinator_code=2669";
private TextView result;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    result = findViewById(R.id.result);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setInitialScale(1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.loadUrl(USGS);
    getWebsite();


}


String title;
**strong text**

private void getWebsite() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
            String category = sharedPrefs.getString(
                    getString(R.string.settings_category_key),
                    getString(R.string.settings_category_default)
            );
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(USGS).get();
                title = doc.body().text();

                String pizur = getSentence(title, category);
                builder.append(pizur).append("\n");


            } catch (IOException e) {
                builder.append("Error : ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    result.setText(builder.toString());
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}

private final Pattern END_OF_SENTENCE = Pattern.compile("16:00|20:50|17:05|08:50|17:00");

public String getSentence(String text, String word) {
    final String lcword = word.toLowerCase();
    String pizur = getString(R.string.pizur_none);
    for (String sentence : END_OF_SENTENCE.split(text)) {
        if (sentence.toLowerCase().contains(lcword)) {
            return sentence;
        }
    }
    return pizur;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(settingsIntent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're completely missing the idea of Jsoup. You use it only to download HTML and parse with regexps. You can use it to select specific parts of HTML without regular expressions.
I guess your getSentence function should look like this:

```
public static String getSentence(Document doc, String word) {
    final String lcword = word.toLowerCase();
    Elements tableRows = doc.select("table#PassListView1 tr"); //selecting all rows of this table
    tableRows.remove(0); // removing first table row because it contains only headers
    Element selectedRow = null;
    for (Element row : tableRows) { // iterating through all the rows ...
        if (row.text().toLowerCase().contains(lcword)) { // ... to find the one you are looking for
            selectedRow = row;
        }
    }
    if (selectedRow == null) { //if no matching row found
        return getString(R.string.pizur_none);
    } else {
        //found matching row, so we're getting all the cells <td>
        Elements tds = selectedRow.select("td");
        for (Element td : tds) { // just displaying contents of every cell
            Log.d("TAG", td.text());
        }
        return tds.get(2).text(); // change number here to get what you want
    }
}
```

imports:

```
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
```

I'm not sure if that's what you wanted to achieve, but it should give you the general idea.

**EDIT** after taking into account advices from comments:

I didn't know exactly what you mean because at the time I was visiting this URL there was only one page of results :) Links to pages 2,3,4... POST specific params to the server. You can observe them in your browser's debugger (network tab). Here's a function that connects to get current values of hidden inputs and POSTs request with page number:

```
private Document downloadPage(int pageNumber) throws IOException {
    Document d = Jsoup.connect(USGS).get(); // first request to get <form> and it's hidden values
    Elements inputs = d.select("#form1 input");
    Connection connectionWithData = Jsoup.connect(USGS);
    for (Element input : inputs) {
        if (input.attr("name").equals("__EVENTTARGET") || input.attr("name").equals("__EVENTARGUMENT")) { // skipping these two params as we will fill them below
            continue;
        }
        connectionWithData.data(input.attr("name"), input.attr("value"));
    }
    return connectionWithData
        .data("__EVENTTARGET", "PassListView1")
        .data("__EVENTARGUMENT", "Page$" + pageNumber)
        .post();
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
Document doc = downloadPage(5);
```

Comment: hi Krystain,thx for your replay but parsing the table wasn't my problem,the problem was getting it as i explained there is a few tables in there that changing every few second automatically or if you press the next button and i am only able to get one (the first one)

Comment: <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('PassListView1','Page$1')" 
    style="color:#4A3C8C;">1</a></td><td><a 
    href="javascript:__doPostBack('PassListView1','Page$2')" 
    style="color:#4A3C8C;">2</a></td><td><span>3</span></td><td><a 
    href="javascript:__doPostBack('PassListView1','Page$4')" 
    style="color:#4A3C8C;">4</a></td>   
this is the code in the website that i think might be the problem 
i can get only the first table how can i get the rest?